# reproducing the format

Tags: frame-title

It would be great if some one help me to reproduce the following title page.

I did it by ps-tricks. But the main problem is that the underlines do not move with respect to length of title, etc.
Thanks.

[image]

Here is what I did:

```
\documentclass[a4 paper]{book}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=210mm,margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\IBox
\sbox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{logo.pdf}}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{pspicture}(-10.5,-14.5)(10.5,14.5)
\rput(0,12){\usebox\IBox}
\psframe[linewidth=5pt](-10.,-14)(10.,14)
\psframe(-8,-8)(8,6)
\psline(-8,9.5)(8,9.5)
\rput(0,10){\textbf{University of }}}
\rput(0,8){Faculty of}
\rput(0,7){PHD thesis}
\rput(0,3.){{\Huge Thesis Title}}
\psline(-3.5,2.)(3.5,2.)
\rput(0,0.5){Author:}
\rput(0,-1.){{\Large The Author}}
\psline(-5,-1.5)(5,-1.5)
\rput(0,-2.5){Advised by:}
\rput(0,-3){{\Large Dr. Advisor}}
\psline(-4,-4)(4,-4)
\rput(0,-6){May 2020}
\psline(-8,-10)(8,-10)
\rput(0,-11){A copyright message}
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us, what you try so far.

Comment: @Zarko I added my source. Thanks

Comment: You should never use a figure environment on a title page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used PSTricks for a long time, and switched to Ti*k*Z for good. So I have some editor macros that convert PSTricks code to Ti*k*Z. I used them on your code and added a style for underlined nodes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=210mm,margin=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newsavebox\IBox
\sbox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-duck.pdf}}% use your logo here


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}\mbox{}\vfill
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[underlined/.style={append after command={
([xshift=-1ex,yshift=-1ex]\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[#1] 
([xshift=1ex,yshift=-1ex]\tikzlastnode.south east)}}]
\node at (0,12){\usebox\IBox};
\draw[line width=5pt](-10.,-14) rectangle (10.,14);
\draw (-8,-8)  rectangle (8,6) (-8,9.5) -- (8,9.5) 
(-8,-10) -- (8,-10);
\node[font=\bfseries] at(0,10){University of};
\node at (0,8){Faculty of};
\node at (0,7){PHD thesis};
\node[font=\Huge,underlined] at (0,3.){Thesis Title};
\node at (0,0.5){Author:};
\node[font=\Large,underlined] at (0,-1.){The Author};
\node (ad) at  (0,-2.5) {Advised by:};
\node[below=1em of ad,font=\Large] {Dr.\ Advisor};
\node at (0,-6){May 2020};
\node at (0,-11){A copyright message};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}\vfill\mbox{}\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

This does not really give full justice to Ti*k*Z, with which one could simplify things more, but it is to give you something which adjusts the underlines and is something to build on.